# How to Schedule azure web job with 2 different Cron expression

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobssdk, azure-webjobs-triggered

I have Created python azure webjob which I want to trigger twice - 1st is daily @2 am and second is every Saturday @ 4 am.

How can I achieve this in a single cron expression?

Below is my current cron expression file looks like:

```
{"schedule":"0 0 14 * * *"}
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible with a single cron expression. You'd better use two different ones and both sharing the same logic.

Comment: You mean to say 2 different webjob

Comment: correct, two differente webjobs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As *@ThiagoCustodio* Said is correct that it is not possible to allow two schedules in one CRON expression and you have to create two Web jobs for achieving your requirement.
- It can be a WebJobs or Functions in the Azure Function, two instances required for 2 different schedules.
- In this SO #[57211407](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57211407), the user *@GeorgeChen* given 3 ways for implementing multiple CRON expressions in Azure Web Jobs with the practical code examples. Those ways are Multiple Static Web Job Methods in *Azure Timer Triggered Function, Custom Schedule Class file, and abstract class custom schedule*r in Azure Web Jobs.